# Snowflake Backup strategy

Tags: snowflake

I am looking to setup rolling backup strategy for snowflake databases. currently I have following setup.

Min Data retention/Time-travel at account level : min 5 days
Fail-safe default : 7 days

I am planning to use stored proc which will clone the database or do the physical data copy at schema level or table level by Creating transient schema/tables.

I would like to minimize cost of storage usage. What would be the best backup strategy to keep 35 days of backup?